# Error while reading a xml (windows-1252) file

Tags: java, xml, windows-1252

I have written a programm in java that should read xml files, but I have got error while reading a xml file with windows-1252:

> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 3

but UTF-8 works for me.

```
public class InputBox {

    public static void XmlOeffnen() throws IOException {


            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int rueckgabeWert = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        String content = null;
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            content = Files.readString(Paths.get(path), Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Converter.Konvertieren(chooser.getName(), content, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already fix it. I just changed the "Charset.defaultCharset()" to "StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1"

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file using the default Charset. If you want to read a file with Windows-1252 encoding, you need to specify that encoding. You can do this with `Charset.forName("windows-1252")` The updated line should look something like:

```
 content = Files.readString(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
```